# How to get items from javascript array to asp.net session

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session

I have a list in javascript and I need save them to MSSQL DB. Please suggest any solution? I want to take them to asp.net cs file with the session.

```
function myFunction() {
            var chks = document.querySelectorAll("#KitapTurs input[type='checkbox']");
            var sayi = chks.length;
            var userchoise = new Array();//this is my array
            for (var i = 0; i < sayi; i++) {
                if (chks[i].checked) {
                    userchoise.push(chks[i].id);
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < userchoise.length; i++) {
                document.write(userchoise[i] + " / ");
            }
//this is javascript session
            sessionStorage.setItem("userchosed", userchoise);
        };
```

I want to save my array to DB in asp.net

Comment: You can use `fetch` to send data from a web browser back to a asp.net page on the server. That page can store the data in the database. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: thanks for your comment @Kokodoko. i am looking for more easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a hidden field and set its value that you want to get at server side

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="DataHolder" name="DataHolder" />
```

Then you can append values to a variable with any delimiter (here it is comma)

```
var userChoiseData = "";
for (var i = 0; i < sayi; i++) {
    if (chks[i].checked) {
        //userchoise.push(chks[i].id);
        //Append values to userChoiseData variable
        userChoiseData = userChoiseData + chks[i].id + ",";
    }
}
```

After loop iteration you will have comma delimited value in the variable `userChoiseData`

Set this as hidden field's value

```
document.getElementById("DataHolder").value = "userChoiseData;
```

Post back the page and get the value at server side (.cs) with:

```
Request.Form["DataHolder"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I think if you want to send that array up to the server side and process it?

It not 100% clear the data type. But I would consider just adding a web method to the page in question.

So, you code say is this:

```
var userchoise = new Array();//this is my array

 for (var i = 0; i < sayi; i++) {
    if (chks[i].checked) {
       userchoise.push(chks[i].id);
    }
 }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'MyWebpageTest.aspx/PassArray',
        data: JSON.stringify({ "MyIdList" : userchoise }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function () {
            alert('ok');
        }
    });
```

And the server side Sub in the web page?

This looks ok:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Sub Pass1(MyIdList As Integer())

    For Each v As Integer In MyIdList
        Debug.Print(v)
    Next
    ' code here to write array of id's to database.

End Sub
```

The above assumes jQuery for the ajax post. Do keep in mind that you not have to set a page post back. Nor bother with a page post back. The effort to get a page post back (with hidden controls) is a bit of setup. And this means you don't need nor have a page post back anyway.

And in above, I put the sub in the same as the web page - but that web page class will NOT have a instance created - so I used "shared" (which is static in c#). So above would become this:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static void Pass1(int[] MyIdList)
{
foreach (int v in MyIdList)
    Debug.Print(v);
}
```

So I think just passing the array up without a bunch of hidden fields, and even having to setup a post back? You can just send the array. A small Sub (void function) that just sends the array to the server means at that point you can do what you please/want with the array. You don't mention if the array is just a list of "id" or has some type of additional structure. I think a hidden field/text box is possible - but you have to execute a post back, and either way its more steps - the ajax calls are really simple, and the types are not only strong, but the json string parameters match what you declare server side - so I think you write the least amount of js code with this approach, and no additonal client side controls are required - except for jQuery.